# Aggregate for non-zero increasing values

Tags: mongodb, set

**TL;DR**

Is there a mongo array operator that can detect if an array contains at least one entry that's larger than the previous?  eg

```
 [1,1,1,2,2,2] -> true
 [1,1,1,0,0,0] -> false
```

---

We're using mongo to track network activity, where the relative field `packets` is the running sum of activity over time.  This is best illustrated by example:

```
[0,0,0,0] -> no packets
[5,5,5,5] -> 5 packets continuous
[0,0,5,5] -> No packets and then a single event of 5
[0,0,5,10] -> two events, each increasing total packets by 5
```

Our goal is to identify records where there has been activity (ie. the number of packets changes).  At first, this seems straightforward using the [$addToSet](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/) operator and then taking sets where count > 1.  EG:

```
[0,0,0,0] -> [0] -> false
[5,5,5,5] -> [5] -> false
[0,0,5,5] -> [0,5] -> true
[0,0,5,10] -> [0,5,10] -> true
```

However, we then learned of an additional constraint.  When activity goes to 0, that is considered a reset and should not count as activity eg,

```
[5,5,0,0] -> false (a reset event)
[0,0,5,5] -> true (a network event)
[5,0,5,0] -> true (a reset event followed be a network event followed by a reset - but because there was a network event this is true)
```

Activity will ALWAYS increase except for when going to zero (ie `[5,5,0,0]` is possible but `[5,5,4,4]` is not).

**Thus, we need to find out if the data contains a single entry whose value is larger than the prior**.  Is there a mongo operator that can sweep through an array and return true if any element is larger than its prior?

Thanks

Comment: Just to be clear, what's `[5,0,5,0]` in your expectation? True or False?

Comment: True - let me update question to reflect

Comment: Oh okay, was a bit worried about that, since that was the only test I was failing. Hate to pick but you just upvoted an answer which actually fails your test cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take advantage of [$reduce](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/index.html) operator to scan the array and keep previous value to compare it with current one.

For sample data like:

```
db.col.save({ data: [1,1,1,2,2,2] })
db.col.save({ data: [1,1,1,0,0,0] })
```

you can run:

```
db.col.aggregate([
    {
        $project: {
            result: {
                $reduce: {
                    input: "$data",
                    initialValue: {
                        previous: { $arrayElemAt: [ "$data", 0 ] },
                        decision: false
                    },
                    in: {
                        previous: "$$this",
                        decision: {
                            $or: [
                                "$$value.decision",
                                { $gt: [ "$$this", "$$value.previous" ] }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            _id: 0,
            result: "$result.decision"
        }
    }
])
```

outputs:

```
{ "result" : true }
{ "result" : false }
```

Comment: Thanks, let me try this out a bit later and mark as accepted if it works which it seems to nicely

Comment: @AdamHughes sure, you can also test it here: https://mongoplayground.net/p/7A1qWH1Qcur

Answer (score 1):

Basically you are traversing with [`$reduce`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/) using current and previous values and comparing

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$addFields": {
    "result": {
      "$reduce": {
        "input": {
          "$range": [ 1, { "$size": "$source_array" } ]
        },
        "initialValue": false,
        "in": {
          "$or": [
            "$$value",
            { "$gt": [
              { "$arrayElemAt": [ "$source_array", "$$this" ]},
              { "$arrayElemAt": [
                "$source_array",
                { "$subtract": [ "$$this", 1 ] }
              ]}
            ]}
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }}
]);
```

Given data like:

```
{ "source_array" : [ 0, 0, 0, 0 ], "expect" : false }
{ "source_array" : [ 5, 5, 5, 5 ], "expect" : false }
{ "source_array" : [ 0, 0, 5, 5 ], "expect" : true }
{ "source_array" : [ 5, 5, 0, 0 ], "expect" : false }
{ "source_array" : [ 5, 0, 5, 0 ], "expect" : true }
{ "source_array" : [ 5, 0, 5, 5 ], "expect" : true }
{ "source_array" : [ 5, 5, 4, 4 ], "expect" : false }
```

Returns:

```
[
  {
    "source_array": [
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0
    ],
    "expect": false,
    "result": false
  },
  {
    "source_array": [
      5,
      5,
      5,
      5
    ],
    "expect": false,
    "result": false
  },
  {
    "source_array": [
      0,
      0,
      5,
      5
    ],
    "expect": true,
    "result": true
  },
  {
    "source_array": [
      5,
      5,
      0,
      0
    ],
    "expect": false,
    "result": false
  },
  {
    "source_array": [
      5,
      0,
      5,
      0
    ],
    "expect": true,
    "result": true
  },
  {
    "source_array": [
      5,
      0,
      5,
      5
    ],
    "expect": true,
    "result": true
  },
  {
    "source_array": [
      5,
      5,
      4,
      4
    ],
    "expect": false,
    "result": false
  }
]
```

All this is done by using [`$arrayElemAt`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/) with the index values from the array. Using [`$range`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/range/) to generate the indexes from `1..length` and comparing `n` with `n-1` for current and previous respectively.

The logic says that no further comparison is needed when a `true` result is obtained.